# Which value should takes to show Gauge value, Fuel pressure or Intake Manifold Pressure?

Tags: obd-ii, fuel-consumption, pressure, gauges

Currently, I'm working on an app which should show Gauge value (inHg) of the vehicle using OBD reader. Which values should I use to show the Gauge? Is there any formula?

Comment: "Gauge value" isn't specific enough since it could refer to multiple fluids. Are you talking about intake air, fuel or engine oil?

Comment: @Zaid it should be air and fuel mixture

Answer (score 1):

Gauge pressure (GP) is linked to absolute pressure (AP) by atmospheric pressure as in :

AP = GP + atmos p

Units can be Bar, Pascals, psi, mmH2O, inHg etc

But you can have them selected based on location ie Bar works well in Europe, psi in UK etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Do you have any idea OBD II ELM327 commands?